# Make template visible on click of link function in Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Probably the question is not phrased correctly . But here is what I am trying to do .

I have a `navbar` defined with countries array that contains the countries' names and coordinates.

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome to the world of directives!</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ng-repeat="countryTab in countries" ng-click="itemClicked(countryTab.label)" style="cursor:pointer">
                    <a>{{countryTab.label}}</a>
                    <country-tab-bar country="selectedCountry"></country-tab-bar>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app',[]);
        app.controller('appCtrl',function($scope){
            $scope.countries = [{
              id: 1,
              label: 'Italy',
              coords: '41.29246,12.5736108'
            }, {
              id: 2,
              label: 'Japan',
              coords: '37.4900318,136.4664008'
            }, {
              id: 3,
              label: 'USA',
              coords: '37.6,-95.665'
            }, {
              id: 4,
              label: 'India',
              coords: '20.5937,78.9629'
            }];
        });
    </script>
```

Now `country-tab-bar` is the directive that has the template that shows the name and the map using the coordinates defined in the array.

I tried

```
    app.directive('countryTabBar',function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope:{
                country: '='
            },
            template: '<div>'+
            '   <div>Italy</div>'+
            '   <br/>'+
            '   <img ng-src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={{country.coords}}&zoom=4&size=800x200"> '+        
            '</div>',
            link : function(scope,elem,attrs){
                scope.itemClicked = function(value){
                    scope.selectedCountry = value;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

But nothing happens on click of the country names.

UI for now is screwed up.

[image]

What needs to be done to fix the same?
Please suggest .
The map should only appear after clicking a name, not before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some minor changes in your code and it is working. *See the comments below*.

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9bz4Lwxa/501/)**

```
    //HTML
    <div ng-app="app">
      <div ng-controller='appCtrl'>
         <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="navbar-header">
                      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome to the world of directives!</a>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                      <!-- pass country to itemClicked function defined into controller -->
                      <li ng-repeat="country in countries" ng-click="itemClicked(country)" style="cursor:pointer">
                          <a>{{country.label}}</a>
                      </li>
                      <!-- directive moved outside the ng-repeat -->
                      <country-tab-bar country="selectedCountry"></country-tab-bar>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </nav>
      <div>
    </div>

    //app
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);

    //controller
    app.controller('appCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.countries = [{
          id: 1,
          label: 'Italy',
          coords: '41.29246,12.5736108'
        }, {
          id: 2,
          label: 'Japan',
          coords: '37.4900318,136.4664008'
        }, {
          id: 3,
          label: 'USA',
          coords: '37.6,-95.665'
        }, {
          id: 4,
          label: 'India',
          coords: '20.5937,78.9629'
        }];

        // function to select the country (receive de full object as parameter)
        $scope.itemClicked = function(selected){
            // set the object needed by the directive
            $scope.selectedCountry = selected
        }

    });

    //directive
    app.directive('countryTabBar',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            country: '='
        },
        template: '<div>'+
        '   <br/>'+
        '   <img ng-src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={{country.coords}}&zoom=4&size=800x200"> '+        
        '</div>',
        link : function(scope,elem,attrs){

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: ..Thanks but I cant really figure out what are the major changes ? Could you please explain a little ? Why was not mine working , and yours is working as expected ?

Comment: If nothing happened when you clicked on the name is because you defined ´itemClick´ inside the directive but call it outside.

Answer (score 1):

Inside

Where is "selectedCountry" defined

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome to the world of directives!</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ng-repeat="countryTab in countries" ng-click="countryTab.showProperty = !countryTab.showProperty" style="cursor:pointer">
                    <a>{{countryTab.label}}</a>
                    <country-tab-bar country="countryTab" ng-show="countryTab.showProperty"></country-tab-bar>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app',[]);
        app.controller('appCtrl',function($scope){
            $scope.countries = [{
              id: 1,
              label: 'Italy',
              coords: '41.29246,12.5736108',
              showProperty: false
            }, {
              id: 2,
              label: 'Japan',
              coords: '37.4900318,136.4664008',
              showProperty: false
            }, {
              id: 3,
              label: 'USA',
              coords: '37.6,-95.665',
              showProperty: false
            }, {
              id: 4,
              label: 'India',
              coords: '20.5937,78.9629',
              showProperty: false
            }];
        });
    </script>


app.directive('countryTabBar',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            country: '='
        },
        template: '<div>'+
        '   <div>Italy</div>'+
        '   <br/>'+
        '   <img ng-src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={{country.coords}}&zoom=4&size=800x200"> '+        
        '</div>'
    }
});
```

Simply hide all country-tab-bar elements using `ng-show` directive which uses new property that if its true the tab is shown if its false its hidden.

the ng-click is assigned to the `li` element which includes both the button to click and the `country-tab-bar` itself. If you want to close it only on the button click move the `ng-click` directive inside the `<a>` element

Comment: Where areyou setting `showProperty` on ng-click ? I am not getting that . Could you lease explain?

Comment: `ng-click="countryTab.showProperty = !countryTab.showProperty"`   here the ng-click is just reversing the boolean of the row.
What i wrote is that each "row" by row i mean `country button` + `countryBar` directive you have property in the model which specifies if the corresponding row should be hidden or not. and you change this property to be the opposite of itself everytime you click. Thats all